# Importing Test Charter from exploratory app into JIRA

Tags: jira-xray, exploratory

I've created a test charter in the exploratory app and now I need to import that charter into the JIRA instance, how can I do that?

Comment: Did you manage to experiment my below suggestion? If it has helped can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XEA connected to Xray (in your Jira instance) you will able to submit your test runs.

Once you submit those, a new Test Run and Test will be created, in the field "definition" of the Test you will find the charter.

If you need more information you can check it here: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XEA/About+Xray+Exploratory+App